# How to stop decrement value on zero in javascript

Tags: javascript

JS:

```
var xAzul = 0;
var Valor = 150;

function adicionarAzul() {
  let azul =  parseInt(++xAzul);
  document.getElementById('quantidadeAzul').innerHTML = azul;
  document.getElementById('SubTotalAzul').innerHTML = azul * Valor;
  calcularSubTotal('+');
}

function subtrairAzul() {
  let azul = parseInt(--xAzul);
  document.getElementById('quantidadeAzul').innerHTML = azul;
  document.getElementById('SubTotalAzul').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('SubTotalAzul').innerHTML) + (- Valor);
  calcularSubTotal("-");
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="subtrairAzul()">
          <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i> 
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="quantidadeAzul">0</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="adicionarAzul()">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i> 
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

When I click on button "-", it don't stops on 0 value. How to stop it?
Plus and subtotal is working, but subtotal value has "-" signal too, when I decrement value.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check to see if the subtraction would be less than zero. If it would be don't update the field.

Comment: It looks like you've left out a bunch of code.

Comment: You can use a basic [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). Only do the subtraction if `xAzul > 0`.

Comment: How? Adding an `If`? Javascript's not my major language...

Comment: Your sample code throws multiple errors (for example: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xAzul is not defined"). Please post the missing code.

Comment: @CyberPlague For one, an [*if statement (conditional)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) is one of the main building blocks of *any* programming language. Second, I linked an article in my previous comment that answers the *"How?"*. Consider taking a look at it; we're here to point you in the right direction but unfortunately you can't rely on StackOverflow to teach you the fundamentals of programming.

Comment: Ok. Forgot. I will delete this post and try by myself. Thanks for all instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have many options:
1. Allow subtraction only if number is greater than 1.
2. Disable the **-** button if the value is === 0.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I will try here!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by disabling the button when you reach `<=0`. You also have to assign unique IDs for each button. Here is an example of that using arrow function:

HTML

```
<form>
  <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="decrement">
          <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#000;">DECREMENT</i> 
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="quantidadeAzul">0</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="increment">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#000;">INCREMENT</i> 
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
const yourNumber = document.getElementById('quantidadeAzul'),
  decrementBtn = document.getElementById('decrement'),
  incrementBtn = document.getElementById('increment');


decrementBtn.onclick = () => {
  if(yourNumber.innerHTML <= 0) {
    decrementBtn.disabled = true
  } else {
    let someNum = parseInt(yourNumber.innerHTML);
    yourNumber.innerHTML = someNum - 1;
  }
}

incrementBtn.onclick = () => {
  let someNum = parseInt(yourNumber.innerHTML);
  yourNumber.innerHTML = someNum + 1;
  decrementBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

The decrement button becomes blurred/`disabled` when the counter hits `0`. However, as soon as you click **INCREMENT** button, `decrementBtn.disabled = false;` enables the **DECREMENT** button back.

If you want to cap your increment, you need to include `>= 20` (you can set this number as high as you like) inside if statement of your increment function. So to be brief, it should look like this:

```
decrementBtn.onclick = () => {
  if(yourNumber.innerHTML <= 0) {
    decrementBtn.disabled = true;
  } else {
    let someNum = parseInt(yourNumber.innerHTML);
    yourNumber.innerHTML = someNum - 1;
    incrementBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}

incrementBtn.onclick = () => {
  if(yourNumber.innerHTML >= 20) {
    incrementBtn.disabled = true;
  } else {
    let someNum = parseInt(yourNumber.innerHTML);
  yourNumber.innerHTML = someNum + 1;
  decrementBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}
```